# Getting non-UI objects to respond to WPF command bindings

Tags: wpf, command

I have a ViewModel class which i want to respond to the built in Refresh command whic is fired from a button but i'm not sure how to declare the CommandTarget.

Briefly, my code is as below

The ViewModel constructor and CanExecute and Executed event handlers -

```
    public ViewModel()
    {
        CommandBinding binding = new CommandBinding(NavigationCommands.Refresh, CommandHandler);
        binding.CanExecute += new CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler(binding_CanExecute);
        binding.Executed += new ExecutedRoutedEventHandler(binding_Executed);
        CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(ViewModel), binding);
    }
    void binding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Print("Refreshing...");
    }

    void binding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }
```

The markup is -

```
<Button Command="Refresh">refresh</Button>
```

Now, I've tried setting the CommandTarget on this button to `{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}` but i get a runtime saying `Cannot convert the value in attribute 'CommandTarget' to object of type 'System.Windows.IInputElement'`.

I'm new to commands so it's entirely possible I'm all kinds of wrong here.  Anyhelp would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RoutedCommand`s and MVVM do not mix. `RoutedCommand`s are tied to the visual tree and to rely on WPF's `CommandBindings` collection. You should implement your own `ICommand` classes that work with the MVVM pattern. Take a look at [Prism's implementations](http://prism.codeplex.com) for starters.

In my own MVVM projects, I have a couple of command implementations:

- `DelegateCommand`. Calls provided delegates to determine whether the command can execute, and to execute the command.
- `ActiveAwareCommand`. Works in conjunction with an interface (`IActiveAware`) and sends command executions to the currently active item. Multiple active aware implementations register themselves with the command, and the command automatically routes `CanExecute` / `Execute` calls to the currently active item.